# Return value between range and use results to compare against different table with no Foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Being a total postgres beginner, am working on a case where I have a table called `range_results` containing:

```
lower| upper | result
1    | 10    | abc
11   | 20    | def
21   | 30    | ghi
... 
n+10 | n+10  | xyz
```

Then I have a table called `codes` which has a single field of data called `numbers` literally containing numbers that could be any of those in the reference set (either exactly the lower, upper or in between). So it is from the `range_results` table that I would like to return the corresponding `numbers` from the `codes` table using those reference values when there is a hit...

My quandary is that I can't do something such as the below query due to the fact there is no FK relation (I believe) as I get a hard error of "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" when I run the query. Thinking initially I would use a `left join`. But still that needs to have a relation...

```
select result from range_results
where lower >= (select numbers from codes)
and upper <= (select numbers from codes)
```

Am I on the right track? Can this existing query be at all salvaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is `left join`:

```
select n.number, rr.*
from numbers n left  join
     range_results rr
     on rr.number >= rr.lower and rr.number <= rr.upper
```